# Start spring boot application faced error "finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Tags: spring-boot

I start spring boot application facing this error below:

```
Execution failed for task ':Application.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 5s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Can anyone help me resolve this. Thank you so much.

I want to start spring boot application